# .NET RegEx for letters and spaces

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression in C# that allows only alphanumeric characters and spaces. Currently, I am trying the following:

```
string pattern = @"^\w+$";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
if (regex.IsMatch(value) == false)
{
  // Display error
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user: FYI, C# does not have regular expression support, unlike JavaScript. You're actually asking about .NET regular expressions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you just need English, try this regex:

`"^[A-Za-z ]+$"`

The brackets specify a set of characters

`A-Z`: All capital letters

`a-z`: All lowercase letters

`' '`: Spaces

If you need unicode / internationalization, you can try this regex:

`@"$[\\p{L}\\s]+$"`

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#word-character-w

This regex will match all unicode letters and spaces, which may be more than you need, so if you just need English / basic Roman letters, the first regex will be simpler and faster to execute.

Note that for both regex I have included the `^` and `$` operator which mean match at start and end. If you need to pull this out of a string and it doesn't need to be the entire string, you can remove those two operators.

Comment: That's not letters, that's ASCII letters. Break everywhere except for the US.

Answer (score 7):

try this for all letter with space :

```
@"[\p{L} ]+$"
```

Comment: Question sounds ".NET RegEx for letters and spaces", nothing about numbers, so this answer is correct one.

Comment: This seems by far the best answer (and one of the few who are correct. Other answers match punctuation or digits sometimes). I just tested this with an online regex tester.

Comment: Added explanation and reference for `\p{L}`

Answer (score 4):

The character class `\w` does not match spaces.  Try replacing it with `[\w ]` (there's a space after the `\w` to match word characters and spaces.  You could also replace the space with `\s` if you want to match any whitespace.

Comment: following up on a comment from Michael under my answer, which I think is more suited here: be aware that `\w` matches more than just letters. It also matches punctuation (dashes, dots, comma's etc): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w3ahtyy.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#WordCharacter

Comment: @Abel: What `\w` matches (aside from letters and decimal digits) is **connector** punctuation.  The full list is [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pc/list.htm), but the only one you're likely to see in practice is `_`, the ASCII low-line or underscore character (`U+005F`).

Comment: `\w` also matches digits.

Answer (score 4):

If, other then 0-9, a-z and A-Z, you also need to cover any accented letters like ï, é, æ, Ć or Ş then you should better use the Unicode properties `\p{...}` for matching, i.e. (note the space):

```
string pattern = @"^[\p{IsLetter}\p{IsDigit} ]+$";
```

Comment: Actually, unless you specify `ECMAScript`, `\w` uses those Unicode properties and more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=VS.100).aspx#WordCharacter

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but the ECMAScript modifier does not influence the behavior of Unicode Properties. It does influence the `\w` behavior. And you're right: `\w` matches far more then just letters, it also matches punctuation like comma's, colons, accents. The `\p{IsLetter} is far more precise and only matches letters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w.aspx

Comment: Yes I think we're saying the same thing ;-) It all depends on what the OP needs. I was simply pointing out that `\w` matches more than `[0-9a-zA-Z]`.  It also includes accented letters for example (unless `ECMAScript` is specified).

Answer (score 1):

This regex works great for me.

```
           Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+");
            if (rgx.IsMatch(yourstring))
            {
                var err = "Special charactes are not allowed in Tags";
            }
```