# Regular Expression for Letters and Spaces

Tags: c#, .net, regex, c#-4.0

I have a string variable in C# and I want to check this string contains letters or not.

I used following regular expression for evaluate this condition, but I returned false in the `if` statement I used.

I dont know why?

My C# Code:

```
 string cellValue ="Row Merging Done here";
 if (Regex.IsMatch(cellValue, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
 {
     messageBox.show("Message found");
 }
```

How to evalute this regular expression?

Comment: Don't you need to recognize spaces: `@"^[a-zA-Z ]+$"`

Comment: @faester Make than an answer, quick :p

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET RegEx for letters and spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950989/net-regex-for-letters-and-spaces)

Comment: `i want to check this string contains alphabets or not` So I think that rather than spaces, the problem is that this regex checks if the string contains *only* letters.

Comment: @faester : thanks faester. i forgot to put a space here.... Please make it as answer...

Comment: @Kookiz: sorry, my string may also contain spaces...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't you need to recognize spaces: `@"^[a-zA-Z ]+$"`

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to check whether the string contains at least one word? If so, you don't need symbols for beginning and end:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(cellValue, @"[a-zA-Z]+"))
```

Comment: but if you want to allow only allowed characters, you need them.

Comment: @eFloh, right. Maybe I've slightly misunderstood the question. If the question was whether the string contains _only_ letters (and spaces, as we found out later) - then the faester's answer is the right one.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:[RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to evaluate your expression